# Resource Error When Creating Xamarin Forms Project Via Standard Template Versus Prism Template

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, prism

Yesterday afternoon, I created a Xamarin forms project using the *standard* blank template.

When I attempt to deploy the project to an Android emulator running version 4.4, the following exception is thrown:

```
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070059'
```

This occurs on the line of code `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);` in `MainActivity.cs` in the Android project.

A forum post ([here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/159738/hello-world-app-crashes-on-samsung-with-android-4-1-api-level-16)) seems to indicate that this is caused by an unsupported (older) version of Android. This seems plausible as it will work if I run the application on a later version. My understanding is that 4.4 is still supported so I am not sure what the issue is. I commented on this forum post but was not sure if anyone would see it as it was marked as resolved.

I marked this question with the Prism tag but it is not a Prism issue. I thought maybe someone from the Prism realm might be able to tell me what is going on since the Prism template is working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some research, I found there is an know issue listed in the [Xamarin.Andorid release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/9/9.4#known-issues-1):

[GitHub 3314](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3314): "`Java.Lang.Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080058`" will abort app execution on **Android 4.4 KitKat (API level 19) or lower** for apps built with AAPT2 that use Android Support Libraries.

**Workaround:**

Add the `--no-version-vectors` option to the `$(AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs)` MSBuild property in your `.csproj` file:

XML

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs>--no-version-vectors</AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then clean and rebuild the project.

Follow the Github thread or the new release note to check the process of this issue:[xamarin/xamarin-android/pull](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/3329)

Comment: This also solves the same issue with Xamarin Android (as opposed to Xamarin Forms). Thanks.